# react-native axios.get() [Error: Request failed with status code 404]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to implement an api from this url (https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/SzS7R74q?version=latest).

**API Link** - https://api.smartable.ai/coronavirus/news/:location

**Headers** - Subscription-Key:3009d4ccc29e4808af1ccc25c69b4d5d

**Path variables** - location: US (Example)

I tested this link on Postman Windows. It is returning me a json response. But when I try it on react native using the same header and path variables, it is returning me the 404 error.

```
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';


export default class NationalNews extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: ''
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.smartable.ai/coronavirus/news/:location', {
            params: {
                "location": "US"   //it maybe just IN
            },
            headers: {
                'Subscription-Key': '429058f92b3246ae9b8ad1cd88daee46',
            },
            method: 'get'

        })
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text></Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Please do help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro axios syntax u are using is not working
Try this code is working fine

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.smartable.ai/coronavirus/news/US', {
        headers: {
            'Subscription-Key': '429058f92b3246ae9b8ad1cd88daee46',
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
}
```